# Date Time picker for bind variable on query panel

Tags: datetime, oracle-adf

I am new to ADF development and am having trouble showing a date time picker on the query panel for a bind variable defined in a query.

The bind variable is used in the where clause of the query and not in the view 
criteria as adding the field required for that is not an option.

I have tried with date and timestamp types as well as the date and default control 
types. The date format is dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss, but I have tried with dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a, yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm and dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm. All without success.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the properties file in another application in the same project had the same name as the one used for the current application and was overwriting the properties. Changing the name fixed the issue